# Why does this example of Forking not need mutex?

Tags: c, pipe, exec, fork, dup2

My professor has this sample code of a function that forks in order to act as a pipe. But how can he ensure that the parent executes before the child without having to use a mutex?

```
void
runpipe(int pfd[])
 {
int pid;

switch (pid = fork()) {

case 0: /* child */
    dup2(pfd[0], 0);
    close(pfd[1]);  /* the child does not need this end of the pipe */
    execvp(cmd2[0], cmd2);
    perror(cmd2[0]);

default: /* parent */
    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    close(pfd[0]);  /* the parent does not need this end of the pipe */
    execvp(cmd1[0], cmd1);
    perror(cmd1[0]);

case -1:
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
}
}
```

Comment: This code looks really bad, because `cmd1` is a global array, why isn't it passed to the function? And `fork()` returns `pid_t` which might be `int`, but it's `pid_t` so you should declare `pid` as `pid_t pid`.

Comment: @iharob I didn't write the code, the global array I left out because it's not necessary, it's just an array of strings. I just need help with the logic behind forking without using locks to maintain order of execution

Comment: You are aware that `forking != threading`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It normally won't matter whether the child or the parent runs first.

If the parent `execvp()`s first and starts writing to the pipe, the write will block once the pipe becomes full, until the child reads some data.

If the child `execvp()`s first and starts reading from the pipe, the read will likewise block until the parent writes some data.

As a side note, the parent will run first on modern Linux kernels (e.g., 3.16.0) after a `fork()`, though that should not be relied on. (Also, the timeslice of the parent might run out right after the `fork()`, making it look like the child runs first.) Some 2.4 kernels ran the child first instead.

The reason the child closes the write end of the pipe and the parent the read end of the pipe is to make sure only one file descriptor remains open for each end of the pipe. (Remember that `fork(2)` duplicates file descriptors.) This means the child will see end-of-file once the parent closes the write end. If the child closes the read end instead and the parent tries to write to the pipe after that, the parent will receive a `SIGPIPE`.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not ensure that the parent executes before the child (from the point of the fork).  Generally speaking, there is no need to enforce such a requirement at this level.

If the child process is going to consume data written to the pipe, then it will probably block trying to read from the pipe until the parent writes something.  I say "probably" because the child could intentionally behave differently.  Both processes can run simultaneously until that point, however, or the child can run before the parent until it blocks.  Where that is an issue, the programs `exec()`ed by parent and child must sort that out amongst themselves.